# Short integral question

Tags: integration

Can anyone here just tell me this is true? I just need a YES/NO, because I am a bit confused right now...

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[{-\frac{x^2}{a}}\right]dx = \left.\left( -\frac{a}{2x} \right)\exp\left[{-\frac{x^2}{a}}\right]\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\end{align}

Comment: No. The right hand is not the primitive of the integrand in the left hand, if that's what you meant to write.

Comment: Yes that is what i wanted to write. Where is the catch here???

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use the chain rule in reverse... the problem is that it doesn't work like that.  You would need to use substitution; unfortunately, though, you don't have an $x$ to cancel out the derivative of $-\frac{x^2}{a}$, and so you can't carry out substitution here.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating the expression on the right-hand side?

Comment: i think you should use polar coordinates

Comment: But there is a rule that $d/dx ~[f(x)] = df(x)/dx  \cdot dx/dx$ ... Why do we have such a rule if it doesnt apply for ALL the functions including exponential? Can anyone provide me a solution to this case?

Comment: I don't know what "rule" are you thinking about: **any** algebraic expression equals itself multiplied by one, so $$\frac d{dx}f(x)=\frac d{dx}f(x)\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac d{dx}f(x) \frac KK$$ when $\,K\,$ is **any** legal mathematical expression...

Comment: I mean we usualy did like this: $\frac{d}{dx}\sin\left(x^2\right) = \underbrace{\cos\left(x^2\right)}_{\frac{d}{dx}\sinqleft(x^2\right)} \cdot \underbrace{2x}_{\rlap{\text{derivative of what is inside the bracket}}}$ The Wolfram alpha confirms it http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20%5Csin(x%5E2)&t=crmtb01

Comment: OMG i wrote my equation a bit wrong and now the "X" mark to edit it is behind the right margin of this webpage. I can't edit... ADMIN PLEASE HELP.

Comment: To see that your antiderivative is wrong, try to differentiate it (use the product rule) and see that you do not get the integrand on the left.

Comment: So I calculated $\int xe^{-x^2/a} dx$ in Wolfram alpha and I can see that the chain rule has been aplied corectly ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x*e%5E%7B-x%5E2%2Fa%7D ) because what i got is $-\frac{a}{2}e^{-x^2/a}$. So why wouldn't a chain rule work if I only remove $x$? Mathematics fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to find out the simplest case (understand and explain each step):

$$I:=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\implies I^2=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}dy=$$

$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy\stackrel{\text{polar coord.}}=\int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^{2\pi}re^{-r^2}d\theta dr=$$

$$=\left.-\pi\int\limits_0^\infty(-2r\,dr)e^{-r^2}=-\pi e^{-r^2}\right|_0^\infty=-\pi(0-1)=\pi$$

and from here

$$I=\sqrt\pi$$

Now your integral, assuming $\,a>0\,$:

$$J:=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/a}dx\;\ldots\;\;\text{substitution}:\;\;u:=\frac x{\sqrt a}\;,\;dx=\sqrt a\,du\implies$$

$$J=\sqrt a\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{a\pi}$$

Comment: oh man i just posted an answer like your answer

Comment: i didn't see your answer i swear

Comment: @what'sup , don't worry: if it bothers you a lot delete your answer, or else leave it as it is and let others decide which approach they like better. This happens a lot with these basic questions and no need to feel bad.

Comment: ok thank you DonAntonio

Comment: Thanks @SamiBenRomdhane , fixed.

Comment: This is wrong: $\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}dy$ How come you use $y$ in place of $x$... I cant just write 2x = 2g...

Comment: 71GA you wanted us to help you and now you say we're wrong ????? look wikipedia maybe you know more about polar coordinate and Gaussian integral and that definite integral is a constant x to y or y to x doesn't change any thing :)

Comment: But $x\neq y$ :((( It never will be. I don't understand...

Comment: look :  let $$\int f(x) \ dx = F(x) + C  \Rightarrow \int_a^b f(x) \ dx = F(a) - F(b) $$ since a and b are constants 1 and 2 for example $$\Rightarrow$$  $$F(a) - F(b)$$ is a constant now by the same way you evaluate $$\int_a^b f(y) \ dy$$

Comment: @71GA, an advice: don't rush to claim something's wrong before you think twice, thrice or 9 times, then you ask for some explanation and then you think again. It is NOT wrong since the integral definition of $\;I\;$ can be given with respect to **any** variable, not necessarily $\,x\,$ , or what is the same: $$\int f(x) dx=\int f(w)dw=\int f(q)dq=\ldots$$ and the same's true for definite, proper or improper, integrals.

Comment: yes 71GA i think you should knew that

Comment: Thank you for this explaination and I am sorry but this $e^x$ function ... I hate it at the moment. Really. Maybee I ll have more questions.

Comment: I downvoted noone ...

Comment: My apologies to you, then. I'll erase that.

Comment: Oh i did ... But i didn't know. It happened because this page is jumping up and down while those advertisments are loading. I fixed the downvote.

Comment: OK, then @71GA ....

Comment: The downvote's still there, @71GA

Comment: the important thing that you understand @71GA

Comment: and me ????????????? :(

Comment: We both are still downvoted, @what'sup ....nothing to worry too much about, though. It happens way more than one would tink.

Comment: you're  right ??

Comment: I'm going to upvote your answer now, @what'sup. You're pretty new here and you need both fair upvotes and not unfair downvotes.

Comment: I upvoted all of you (I hope it helps). This wouldn't be the first time this happened. This page is somehow bugged it seems.

Comment: thank you very much @DonAntonio

Comment: @71GA , the page's fine. Perhaps you should try another browser since, as noted, the downvotes still are there.

Comment: but Don i actually don't know what does the upvoting do ?

Comment: What does it do, @what'sup? It "gives" you $\;10\;$ reputation points, whereas a downvote "takes" off your reputation $\;2\;$ points.

Comment: @DonAntonio but i am using a Google Chrome it is the best :)

Comment: I think i understand everything now exept this: $\left.-\pi\int\limits_0^\infty(-2r\,dr)e^{-r^2}=-\pi e^{-r^2}\right|_0^\infty$ How do you do this?

Comment: @71GA : $$-2r = (-r^2)'\implies \int(-2r)e^{-r^2}dr=e^{-r^2}$$as you can easily check by differentiating $\,e^{-r^2}\;$ ...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

To find the value of the integral:

Multiply the  integral by $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[{-\frac{y^2}{a}}\right]dy$ then use the polar coordinates.

Comment: Nice suggestion, Sami.

Answer (score 1):

evaluate $$ \large{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{a}} \ dx} $$

now we have $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{a}} \ dx \ dy = 4\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{a}} \ dx \ dy $$
(ok i like 0 to inf ) to polar coordinate

$$4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{\infty} re^{-\frac{r^2}{a}} \ dr \ d\theta$$

now it became easy and note that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{a}} \ dx \ dy = \left(\large{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{a}} \ dx} \right)^2 $$